# How to use return * in neo4jclient

Tags: neo4jclient

Can anybody help me to convert this cypher query into neo4jclient

```
MATCH (a)-[r]-(p:Post) RETURN *
```

Here what I have done so far

```
Match("(a)-[r]-(p:Post)").Return<object>(*);
```

but will return an error saying : 
Neo4j returned a valid response, however Neo4jClient was unable to deserialize into the object structure you supplied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Return<T>` requires you a type, so that Neo4jClient knows how to deserialize the response into objects. It can't take a pile of different node shapes and jam them into instances of `object`, so hence it failing.

You'll need to do something like:

```
Return((a, p) => new
{
    Author = a.As<Author>(),
    Post = p.As<Post>()
})
```

Remember, C# is a statically type language.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think you are absolutely right but I was trying to solve some other problem That force me here. I will try to explain the entire problem that i am facing in a new Question.  but as far as this question you gave me the answer.